# Swift 3 - Formatting Time String from String.CharacterView formatted string

Tags: ios, json, swift, string, swift3

I am trying to figure out how to format a string that has already been formatted using String.CharacterView.

The code is:

```
let formattedDate = arrivalTime.characters.suffix(8) //gets the last 8 characters of a JSON outputted string for the time
 record.time = String(formattedDate) //sets the characters to a string and then sets that equal to the record class variable time, which displays the string in each table view cell
 self.records.append(record)
```

Which results in a string like

```
18:41:21
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to get a string like

```
6:41pm
```

instead of 18:41:21

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your string using components(separatedBy: ":") and map the elements into integers. Then you can format your result string using the first component (hour) truncating remainder dividing by 12 and conditionally add `am` or `pm` based on its value:

```
let time24h = "18:41:21"
let components = time24h.components(separatedBy: ":").flatMap{Int($0)}
if components.count > 1 {
    let time12h =  String(format: "%d:%02d", components[0] % 12, components[1])
        + (components[0] < 12 ? "am" : "pm")  //  "6:41pm"
}
```